# Where can I see Server http header?

Tags: security, http-headers

One of our applications is tested by Whitehat Sentinel and one of their findings was that in some cases our response header for Server is set to:

> > Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

I have tried accessing the URL they identified with Postman and Fiddler but I do not see the Server header. I have also tried an online web sniffer http://web-sniffer.net/

Can someone advise how I can see this header?

In Chrome Network tab I see these headers

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=300
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 13:59:15 GMT
Content-Length: 1245
```

No Server header.

The URL reported by Whitehat was not working for me, I changed the target URL to domain.com/%% and this caused the request to be handled by http.sys and it returned the Server attribute.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the name of the header. That is the value found in the `Server` header when an application serves files over HTTP via `http.sys`, which is the kernel-mode HTTP server built into Windows.

For example, when serving a file via a C# `HttpListener`, I get this header:

```
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

This header can be disabled by setting the following registry value:

- Key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
- Name: `DisableServerHeader`
- Type: `DWORD`
- Value: `1`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will reword question. I do not see the server header though.

Comment: Are you sure your tools aren't just hiding it as unimportant? I usually use the Network tab of Firefox's dev tools.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're sending the exact same request? It is possible that valid requests do not receive the `Server` header because they are handled by the application's code. Invalid requests never make it to the application's code and get handled by `http.sys` internally and thus get the default header. For example: http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2013/01/09/asafaweb-excessive-headers-and-windows-azure/